# Accessing model data in a loop

Tags: loops, yii2

I have data stored in `$model->data1, $model->data2 etc...`
I want to access each data via loop

So I'm trying to do

```
$i=1
while($i<10) {
echo $model->data.$i
$i++;
}
```

but receive error getting unkown property `$model->data`, which means program cannot understand my trick with adding number to data. Is there way to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yout can use this approach: `$model->{'data'.$i}`

```
$i=1
    while($i<10) {
    echo $model->{'data'.$i};
    $i++;
}
```